# How do I make a Subshell a part of an alias?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-alias

I'm not sure what is the correct way to describe my problem, so here's an example:

`alias ashell='adb shell su $(stat -c %u /data/data/com.termux) -s /data/data/com.termux/files/home/bin/termuxshell'`

Instead of having to `adb forward` and `start termux.homeActivity`, then SSH into Termux, the idea is that I just use the adb shell and `su` into Termux instead (not ideal I'm told as it doesn't behave correctly, but it does what I need it to)

While runing the comand as is works just fine, it fails when aliased as it tries to run the subshell (`$(stat -c %u /data/data/com.termux)`) on the local machine instead of the remote one, resulting in a failure because I don't have the dir on my local device.

Would a function work instead/be a better solution? or is there a way to delimit the subshell and pass it on to adb instead?

P.S. Hardcoding the subshell return is not ideal as I have multiple devices and the value may change anyhow.

Comment: What would you use to run it directly from CLI, *without* an alias?

Comment: @user1686 the alias without `alias ashell='...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is the same as in the post
[How to define an alias without executing dollar signs contained inside?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298556/how-to-define-an-alias-without-executing-dollar-signs-contained-inside)

The accepted
[answer by Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298564/17660)
is to escape the dollar sign using `\`, but he recommends instead
to use a shell function.

See the answer for more details.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I can't try it now, but I think I was right to use functions instead of aliases